# Interrogative form for the status related sentence

Tags: interrogatives, stative-verbs

Which one is the correct interrogative form of the below sentence:

This proxy server is an Apache-Http instance.

```
Is this proxy server an Apache-Http instance?

                       OR

Does this proxy server is an Apache-Http instance?
```

Comment: First one is correct, BE does not take the auxiliary IS.

Answer (score 1):

The first one in your question i.e.,

> Is this proxy server an Apache-Http instance?

is correct.

But the second one i.e.,

> Does this proxy server is an Apache-Http instance?

is wrong because 'Do, Does, Did' is not followed by an auxiliary verb. They're always followed by the base (root) form of verbs.